# how to add different state for a specific key of a custom keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-button

i wanted to change the background color/image of a specific key in my custom keyboard.I am following google softkeyboard source code. i wanted to edit my key into the onDraw method of the LatinKeyboardView which extends KeyboardView. here is my code

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(25);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for (Key key : keys) {
        if (key.sticky) {
            // Log.d("DEBUG",key.label.toString());

            NinePatchDrawable npd = (NinePatchDrawable) context
                    .getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_nine);
            npd.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y
                    + key.height);
            npd.draw(canvas);
            if (key.icon != null) {
                 key.icon.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
                 key.icon.draw(canvas);
            }

        }


    }

}
```

in this onDraw method i successfully customize a specific key(which is shift key in my case) but i can't add different state for this key.i thought if i change the code in this

```
NinePatchDrawable npd = (NinePatchDrawable) context
                    .getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mybutton);
```

and make mybutton.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_nine_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_nine"></item>

</selector>
```

but i got classCastException when i run this. I think their might be other way to this this. Please any one who know this trick guide me. thanks in advance. N.B: all i wanted to add different state to this custom key :)

Answer (score 0):

Your drawable isn't a 9 patch, so you can't cast it as one.  Use it as a standard Drawable.

Comment: i use standard Drawable. this time no error but the image does not change when the state change.....i think this is not the way to do it......any clue? @Gabe Sechan

Answer (score 0):

Put `android:state_pressed` before the `android:drawable`.